# Node.JS convert Variable-length binary data to jpeg or png?

Tags: image, node.js, binary, variable-length

I was wondering how to convert `Variable-length binary data`(`255216255224016747073700110010100255`) to a jpeg or png to the web browser?

**Example Code:**

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

    var config = {
        "userName": "user@server.database.windows.net",
        "password": "pswd",
        "server": "server.database.windows.net",
        "options": {
                "database": "db",
                "encrypt": true,
        }
    };

    var connection = new Connection(config);

    connection.on('connect', function(err) {
            console.log("Connected");
        }
    );

var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var result,
    resG;

    function sendResponse() {
        var vals;
            // Convert to string then array
        var resultA = result.toString().split(',');
            // Now I can loop through the data returned
        resultA.forEach(function(val, index, ar) {
            if(vals == null) {
                vals = val;
            } else {
                vals += val;
            }   
        });
        resG.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Length': vals.length});
        //console.log(vals);
        //resG.end("<img src=\"data:image/jpg;base64," + vals + "\" />");
            // Output data returned from db as string
        resG.end("" + vals);
    }

    function executeStatement() {
         request = new Request("SELECT Photos FROM dbo.tbl WHERE FarmerFirstName='someName' AND FarmerLastName='someLastName'", function(err, rowCount) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
                }
            });

            request.on('row', function(columns) {
                columns.forEach(function(column) {
                    result = column.value;
                });
            });

        request.on('doneInProc', function(rowCount, more) {
                    // Got everything needed from db move on to sending a response
            sendResponse();
        });

            connection.execSql(request);
    }

var http = require('http'),
    director = require('director');

var router = new director.http.Router({
    "/": {
        get: executeStatement
    }
});

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
  // set global res var
  resG = res;
  router.dispatch(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end();
    }
 });
});

server.listen(80);
```

I'm using **tedious** for my db connector and **director** as my router.

Comment: What do mean by convert it to a JPEG? What is the original data?

Comment: Convert the data to base64 string and use as a dataUri in the browser. `new Buffer(data).toString('base64')`

Comment: @loganfsmyth the original data is in the parenthesis but not all of it because its 40,000+ characters. Also I need to convert it to a jpeg because when the header `Content-Type` is set to `image/jpeg` it can't render it correctly.

Comment: @camelCaseD Sorry, the part that is confusing me is that you say binary data, but your example data is numbers. Is that hex, or base64, or what? If it's a string, what format is that data in? And to confirm, that data already JPEG, right? If not, what does converting an arbitrary binary value into a JPEG even mean?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yes the data is already jpeg. Its [`Variable-length binary data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) from a mssql db.

Comment: @camelCaseD That is the type on the database side, but what is the type in Node? Is it a string, a Buffer? If you show some sample code or explain how you got the example value you are printing, it might be easier. What library are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I  updated my question with the example code

Comment: Thanks for the example code. Your `toString` and `split` calls obscure the original data, so it was impossible to guess what the initial data was. Do you want to serve this image as an HTML page with a data URL, or do you want to serve an actual image file with `content-type` `image/jpeg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `result` is already an array of bytes for the Image. You do not need to do any fancy transformations on it. This should work.

```
function sendResponse() {
    resG.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', 'Content-Length': result.length});

    resG.end(new Buffer(result));
}
```

or if you want to serve it as part of an HTML page, this:

```
function sendResponse() {
    resG.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    var vals = (new Buffer(result)).toString('base64')

    resG.end("<html><body>" +
        "<img src=\"data:image/jpg;base64," + vals + "\" />" +
        "</body></html>");
}
```