# Node : how to convert from varbinary to image of SQL Server datatype

Tags: node.js, angular, express, node-mssql

I'm have a SQL Server database with images of type `varbinary`. I need to convert the `varbinary` and return the image to a web page. Help would be appreciated.

I found this and it was very helpful, but I need it in reverse.
[Node.js How to convert to image from varbinary of MS Sql server datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042527/node-js-how-to-convert-to-image-from-varbinary-of-ms-sql-server-datatype)

Something like ...

```js
var image  = new Buffer(rs.recordset[0].Image).toString('base64');
                    res.type('image/jpeg; charset=utf-8');
                    res.status(200).end(image);
```

```html
<ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of images">
          <img class="center-block" src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{image}}">
        </ng-template>
```

And my service is like this ...

```js
 getImage(query){
    
       return this._http.get(this.API_URL + this.baseUrl + query)
         .map(res => res.json());
    
   }
```

Comment: may this link help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667553/node-js-convert-variable-length-binary-data-to-jpeg-or-png

Answer (score 1):

This was the answer.

```js
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
//var image = rs;
var image  = new Buffer(rs.recordset[0].Image);
res.end(image);
```